# How to get the first column (index) in the dictionary output with Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have not used pandas before but it looks like it could be a really nice tool for data manipulation. I am using python 3.7 and pandas 1.2.3.

I am passing a list of dictionaries to the dataframe that has 2 pieces to it. A sample of the dictionary would look like this:

```
data = [
    {"Knowledge_Base_Link__c": null, "ClosedDate": "2021-01-06T19:02:14.000+0000"}, 
    {"Knowledge_Base_Link__c": "http://someurl.com", "ClosedDate": "2021-01-08T21:26:49.000+0000"}, 
    {"Knowledge_Base_Link__c": "http://someotherurl.com", "ClosedDate": "2021-01-09T20:35:58.000+0000"}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Then I format the ClosedDate like so
df['ClosedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ClosedDate'],  format="%y-%m-%d", exact=False)

# Next i get a count of the data
articles = df.resample('M', on='ClosedDate').count()

# print the results to the console
print(articles)
```

These are the results and exactly what i want.

[image]

However, if i convert that to a list or when i push it to a dictionary to use the data like below, the first column (index i presume) is missing from the output.

```
articles_by_month = articles.to_dict('records')
```

This final output is almost what i want but it is missing the index column.

This is what i am getting:

```
[{'ClosedDate': 15, 'Knowledge_Base_Link__c': 5}, {'ClosedDate': 18, 'Knowledge_Base_Link__c': 11}, {'ClosedDate': 12, 'Knowledge_Base_Link__c': 6}]
```

This is what i want:

```
 [{'Date': '2021-01-31', 'ClosedDate': 15, 'Knowledge_Base_Link__c': 5}, {'Date': '2021-02-28', 'ClosedDate': 18, 'Knowledge_Base_Link__c': 11}, {'Date': '2021-03-31', 'ClosedDate': 12, 'Knowledge_Base_Link__c': 6}]
```

Couple things i have tried:

```
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
# This just takes the sum and puts it in a column called index, not sure how to get date like it is displayed in the first column of the screenshot

# I also tried this
df['ClosedDate'] = df.index
# however this gives me a Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index' error.
```

I thought this would be simple and checked the pandas docs and many other stacked articles but i cannot find a way to do this. Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an additional key in the dict with

```
articles.reset_index().to_dict('records')
```

But BEFORE that you have to rename your index since `ClosedDate` (the index' name) is already a column:

```
articles.index = articles.index.rename('Date')
```

Comment: amazing response time and this is exactly what i needed. Thank you so much!